# Fast YUI Editor

Tags: php, windows, ide, yui, sublimetext2

I am used to metapad (basically a more fault tolerant notepad), dreamweaver (memory hog with neat syntax highlighting, and basic error detection), and hotdog (antique, dont use this anymore!).

What I want to do is migrate to a better editor that isn't a memory hog like dreamweaver, but also is closer to the edge of production programming. I use SFTP alot with my internals, FTP basic with my external projects, and I also want to use SVN. <- Most of these protocols dont need to be built into the editor, but it would be nice.

My question is this;

I have looked at Sublime Text 2, the responsiveness is amazing, but it's broken. Alot. And every time someone mentions this. They suggest that it will be that way cause it's a "beta" release.

Is there something else that I should use that is similar or uses the same plugins? How do I make sublime more stable short of de-compiling the thing, and trying to hack it to behave with Windows? (or perhaps, Simple Text 2 is purely for Mac users?) Let me know!

My Target Market;
Speed, Lightweight (Aptana & Dreamweaver use around ~150MB memory), Keyboard intensive preferred (or at least shortcut friendly), works in portable mode (install not required)

Platforms required; Windows 7/XP, Linux CentOS 6.x (with PuTTY please?)

Platforms wanted; Android OS / Apple iOS - friendly with bluetooth support (?)

Syntax highlighting/coding specific for/with; *Important
PHP 5.x, MySQL, YUI

Syntax highlighting supported for; *Not so important
HTML, XML, and maybe.. YAML/MongoDB (?)

Works with or does something similar to; (Zen Coding - fast way to write repetitive tasks)
http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/

I DO NOT care for;
Debuggers.. why? Because I can write debugger stuff in my own code, and often.. even inside of dreamweaver I never use their test browser cause I always end up wanting to use a full-fledged browser with extensions like firebug/ySlow inside of IE9, Firefox 12, Chrome, etc.

** Updated with more specific requirements.

Comment: +1 for the broken Sublime Text :)

Comment: Damn. I thought I was on SuperUser when I replied. This doesn't belong on SO, I think. It should probably be migrated to SU.

Comment: SO? SU? No idea what your saying, clarify please?

Comment: Well this is interesting... Sublime works alot better on my Dev Computer, but terribly on my test system. Will look into this more.. I think this has to do with Python 2.7 bundle I installed... :O

Comment: So.. I installed python 2.7 just like my dev system, and its still terribly slow. I'm starting to think that Sublime Text 2 is designed exclusively with Windows 7 code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you value stability and robustness. My long-time text editor on Windows was [UltraEdit](http://www.ultraedit.com/). It's not one of the "hip" new editors, but it's solid and has support for a lot of things, though it does take some configuration to get going. It isn't free, however. All the open source or free text editors I've found for Windows (esp. Notepad++, which is often recommended) are even more "broken" than Sublime Text 2 (which I find to be pretty good, actually).

On Mac, I use [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/) which is free, stable, and great. I have no idea how you intend to find a text editor that'll actually on Mac, Windows *and* Android (the first two I understand... the latter, however, will naturally be a completely different product).

Both UltraEdit and TextWrangler have been around for a long time and have had most of their kinks and quirks worked out. They're reliable products and can be trusted to simply handle whatever you throw at them, in my experience.

Comment: Sublime Text 2 is based on a python wrapper. Practically everything runs off of that. I havent really researched into iOS, and Android. I looked at this; http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-and-tips/sublime-text-2-tips-and-tricks/  ||  The iPad/Android interest is mostly cause I own a android cell phone, and I find the iPad interesting >> http://applidium.com/en/applications/vim/

Comment: It's not a matter of whether or not it runs on an OS, it's a question of whether or not it was designed for it. It can run but still be virtually unusable.

Comment: I really appreciate your feedback. The answer was portable sublime text 2 is not written properly, but the installer fixes 90% of the issues. I also installed notepad++, and I will try that one out as well! :)